# Laravel custom interface placement

Tags: php, laravel-5, interface, autoload

I am making a blog with Laravel and here, users can subscribe for newsletters. The thing is I am planning to use mailchimp and I need to make all the necessary interfaces, classes and service providers.
After watching laracasts take on this, they put all the files in `app\Acme\Newsletters` and `app\Acme\Notify`. But that was in Laravel 4. Now there are separate folders for providers. So should place interfaces and classes in `app\Blog\Newsletters` and service providers in their dedicated folder, or all in one?
And since in the autoload there is already a psr-4 directory defined

`psr-4 : {"App\" : "app/"}`

I do not need to edit the autoload, since the Blog directory is inside the `app/`?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/lessons/bulk-email-notifications-part-1# link to the laracasts video on bulk emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your own decision where to place your classes and interfaces as laravel uses psr-4 autoloading. You only need to pay attention to your namespace usage. If you want to place your classes within app\Blog\Newsletters you must namespace them with `\App\Blog\Newsletters`. As [services providers are registered](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers#registering-providers) within config\app.php you are also free to place them everywhere you want. Laravel resolves this for you.